# linq to sql, why to use it in MVC instead of traditional queries?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

is it necessary to use LINQ for sql purposes in MVC ? can't we use traditional queries like:

```
Select name from tbl where id = 2;
```

instead of LINQ ? and why linq in any case ?

Comment: Are you aware that you're going to have to _do_ something with that query? The string by itself isn't going to retrieve data from the database.

Comment: just example, yeah i know i missed id in it

Comment: `id` isn't what I meant. I mean you're going to have to run that through SqlDataReader or something.

Comment: example sir just example it is

Comment: The **main** benefit of any ORM (object-relational mapper) is that you get back **nice proper .NET objects** that you can work with - a `Customer` or a `List<Customer>` - instead of untyped, hard-to-handle, messy rows and columns only, in a raw ADO.NET query. An ORM can do a lot of the uninteresting, boring mapping work for you - but hey - if you **want** to write a lot more boring left-to-right-assignment code - feel free to go ahead and do so! No one is forcing you to use an ORM ....

Answer (score 5):

ASP.NET MVC in no way restricts your choice of data access technology. In fact, model binding works with objects, and MVC has no idea whether your objects represent some database or not.

Besides, if you were to use LINQ at all, you would do best to use Entity Framework (a.k.a. LINQ to Entities) and not LINQ to SQL, which is much more limited.

Answer (score 4):

Linq to SQL, EntityFramework, nHibernate - are ORM (Object-relational mapping) tools. ORM represent database objects as standard .NET classes.

Raw SQL can be used, when you are inserting a lot of data, and you need a good performance. In all other cases you should to use ORM.

And if you decide to use ORM, I advise you to use EntityFramework; it's more powerful than LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use linq at all. I usually use dapper.net for my data layer, mapping SQL queries to objects. It's personal preference.

Comment: ok so in Model layer of MVC, can i use simple select queries etc and can they be accessed by controller for view part ?

Comment: The simplest way of doing it is querying the database in the controller. Mapping the result of the query to a model and returning the model to the view. The view displaying the data held in the model. Personally, I will usually push data access off to a repository layer (class project,) the controller can query the database through the repository. If the project is complicated, I might have a business layer in between the controller and the repository layer. This makes the controllers clean and light weight, the business logic being carried out in the business layer.

Answer (score 3):

You **are not obliged** to use Entities Framework, as you are not obliged to use anything in particular.

Microsoft strongly suggests using the [Entities Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) because it is an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) integrating very easily with the whole Microsoft ecosystem, using the [LINQ query language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx) which is integrated in the .NET languages specification. This integration happens through the [Linq to Entities query language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the respective tools provided in Visual Studio.

As you will see, Entities Framework (as every other ORM) has the overhead of the learning but in my opinion, it totally pays you back as using an ORM leads to faster development and more maintainable source code. I would strongly suggest using an ORM (it has many [advantages](http://karwin.blogspot.gr/2009/01/why-should-you-use-orm.html)) and I suppose since you are already familiar with Microsoft ecosystem, Entities Framework would be the best choice.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to use this style of queries you can use **stored procedures** this is to close to the normal query, just and a Linq-to-SQL file into your project and drag and drop you **stored procedures** then you can use them like methods and this is a link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386946.aspx

**Note that** *Linq-to-SQL is integrated only with SQL Server*

Comment: also I think it is more suitable with MVC

Comment: Why do you think it's more suitable?

Comment: because of the way of programing in MVC is more suitable with LinQ more than ADO ... well for me at least

Comment: @AyaMohammad: so what's that got to do with LINQ to SQL? Honestly, any other ORM would be better than LINQ to SQL.

Comment: @jhonSaunders your experience is better than me sure ,but as I said in my 2nd comment "at least for me" , I mean from my point of view and my experience between ADO and LinqtoSql ,I've found that LinQ is suitable for me and satisfies my needs as well

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to use LINQ at all, or any other ORM frameworks, you an work directly against a database.

In .Net this is typically done using ADO.Net, for example using the System.Data.SQL namespace.
See code examples and official documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx#_SqlClient)